# Files not accessible

Tags: windows, disk-space, temporary-files

My system is running on a PC with C:\ Drive out of space. So I tried to delete some files and clean up to get more space. I found that the *%Temp%* (`C:\Users\Username\AppData\Local\Temp`) takes lots of space and tried to delete files in it. But when I open it , it alerted me with the message:

`C:\Users\Username\AppData\Local\Temp is not accessible`

The file or directory is corrupted and unreadable? What to do? Is deleting files from Temp harmful to computer?

Comment: Depends on the Windows version, assuming 10, type 'storage settings' in search bar > storage sensor > Temporary files > Clean now.

Answer (score 0):

What's your operating system? Win Vista/7 or XP?

Try running chkdsk C: /F

If it doesn't help try restarting to safe-mode (F8 during boot > Select Safe Mode) and try to delete files from there

**UPD:**
I guess Microsoft actually forces you to use their tools, such as [Disk cleanup](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows-vista/Delete-files-using-Disk-Cleanup)

I hope that it has been improved since Windows XP, and actually DOES delete temp files...

Besides that you should try deleting restore points and stuff like that...

Offtopic: Actually I had the same problem with Windows 7 conquering my SSD's free space (WinSxS folder, Temporary files, etc...) This made me move to Gentoo Linux, now I have Windows 7 as QEMU virtual machine for few things that I don't do often...

Comment: my OS is windows 7

Comment: Try this thing: Open your start menu and type `cmd`. When **Command Line** appears in list - right click it and choose `Run as Administrator`. Navigate to %TEMP% dir with `cd %TEMP%` then try to delete all files with `del *.*`. Something like that.

Comment: the result is: are you sure (y/n)

Comment: i pressed y and the result is same as the file/dir is corrupted and unreadable

Comment: Make sure that you are actually in TEMP folder and press **y**

Comment: OK. Did you try chkdsk ?

Comment: yes i have done it .. but the same alert

Comment: Try this [link](http://serverfault.com/questions/72561/64-bit-tortoisesvn-on-windows-7-says-file-or-directory-is-corrupted-and-unreada)

Comment: its returning  the type of file system is NTFS the type of file system is ntfs . canno lock the current drive

Comment: It should notify you to try chkdsk on next reboot actually

Comment: I've updated my answer, take a look please...

Comment: "MS forces you to use their tools" - I can go into `C:\Users\Username\AppData\Local\Temp` and delete all files manually. I can use any other utility such as CCleaner as well. The error clearly indicates something's messed up with the file system of the OP's machine.

Comment: @Karan Whether `chkdsk` doesn't help, or it hasn't been tried

Comment: OP said he got a "Cannot lock the current drive" error. As you stated, chkdsk should have been scheduled to run during the next boot, but I don't see any indication that he actually did this.

Comment: @Karan Hard drives these days are not what they used to be...